# javascript click event :click once trigger twice callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently building a "simons game", according to the FCC project ([here](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-simon-game)).
  In my first version(not fully functional) demo, I find a weird bug, every time I click buttons(the colored div) once, the callback function "startAnswer" will be called twice, so the game will not be played correctly, here is my code at CodePen.io.
  `my code`: https://codepen.io/NxDon/pen/eRpRra

here is a note about how my code works:

1. I create a game object by new GameConstructor(line 99);
2. I bind callback functions to "start" and "strict" button.
3. when player click the "start" button, the callback function "startGame"(line 17) will be invoked, It will initialize some parameters, and display the answer for player to repeat;
4. **when the display is over, I click one of the four ring area(which I refer as the button), to match the answer. the ring area has bound its click event with callback function "startAnswer(line 55)" at the game start phase, my intuition is the if I click the ring area once, the callback function will invoke once, instead, the startAnswer was continuously invoked twice. That the part It confuses me. Thanks for your help.**

Comment: Your code is very large so pls Mention here which button you are clicking and its call to call back function "startAnswer" twice so that it will be more clear.

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo Thanks for your tip, I have already added some abstract for my code, the whole point is that I click one of the ring areas once, but the callback function "answerStart" was invoked twice for whatever reason it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than 1 listener for the button ,

```
$(id).off('click');//removes past listeners
$(id).click(function(){
    startAnswer();
});
```

https://codepen.io/smsbhatt/pen/yXYPWW

Comment: You are right, every time I enter the new level, I new click handler will be bound to the div, thanks.

Comment: your setClickable function triggers more than once.

Comment: make it according to your requirements, ive not understood your game strategy.

Comment: i hope it ll help you.

Comment: Big help indeed

Comment: if you interested in the game strategy, click here [link](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-simon-game)